# nextcloud multiple trusted domains not works in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

Based on nextcloud [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud) :

- `NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS` (not set by default) Optional
  space-separated list of

domains
This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
  db:
    container_name: maria-db
    restart: always
    image: mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --log-bin=ROW --innodb-read-only-compressed=OFF
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ncdb
      MYSQL_USER: nextcloud
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: nextcloud
    volumes:
      - /containers/cloud/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

  nextcloud:
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: always
    image: nextcloud:17.0.0
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /containers/cloud/nextcloud/apps:/var/www/html/apps
      - /containers/cloud/nextcloud/config:/var/www/html/config
      - /containers/cloud/nextcloud/data:/var/www/html/data
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=${NCADDRESS} nextcloud
```

But it doesn't create second array element in `config.php` file.
Also i used the env like this too:

```
         NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS: ${NCADDRESS} nextcloud
```

But no differences:

```
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => 'nc.example.com',
  ),
```